# Can I host the same domain I've used as a nameserver?

Tags: domain, vps, nameserver, godaddy

I've setup a domain I have as NS1.DOMAIN.COM for my other sites. But there seems to be an issue with actually getting it to be viewed as a website. I'm currently using VESTA and my registrar is GoDaddy. Any suggestions about things I should check into would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**That's an odd thing to do.**

I suggest you don't use ns1.domain.com as a web server. It's probably your name server, which points to a different address.

Tell me your domain or post your zone (DNS config) and I'll look at it. There's probably something wrong.

Also, maybe you should post your web server configuration as well... I suspect you could have more than one *issue*.

If you don't put enough information into your question, people can't help you. And people will down vote you and vote to close your question.

**Things you should check:** Your DNS config and web server config. More advice is pending. Waiting on details.

Comment: It's basically a VPS, and I set up a DNS Template using the IP of the server.  There was no NS available,  so I made one from a domain I own on GoDaddy. This is basically something I've setup so I can learn about it.

Comment: I've read a bunch of articles about gluing it,  but they're all from ten years ago and aren't even relevant when it comes to navigating around GoDaddy to make the changes/corrections.  One of the only tips that seemed positive was to use FreeDNS to setup the nameserver.

Comment: @SteveVentimiglia 1. You need a nameserver for every domain, usually there are at least two. 2. Quite often they are called ns1 ans ns2 3. You can't host a website before you have a your domain working properly. 4. You can only use Serverfault to solve business IT problems and it's not clear that's what you're doing. 5. Your question is about to get closed for being off-topic. 6. I warned you yesterday, it might be too late. 7. Consider another StackExchange community like SuperUser or something. 8. When you get there still follow my instructions. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I had actually done everything the way it needed to be done and became frustrated since it wasn't working.  The issue was more about a setting in Vesta that I was overlooking in my "n00b" phase of playing with setting up a VPS host and the Vesta CP.  However, it would be extremely kind of Google to stop 10-14 yr. old sets of "instructions" (aka "destructions") from showing up first on their SERPs when there is zero benefit to them.  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: I've accepted your answer, based on the advice you've posted and the help you were attempting to provide. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done: the A record for the name server domain has to point to a server running DNS. That server can also run a webserver, so the same server can respond to web requests.

However, it is a bad idea to do this.